# Android how to create dynamically activities

Tags: android

I'm working on android app that loads html pages and presents to the user.
When the user logs in the app gets list of URLs. Each user gets different pages.
Is it possible to create activities as the number of html pages for each user?

Comment: Better to create `Fragment` dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create dynamic activities but you can create dynamic views inside single activity.
For you problem create single activity and try to add dynamic views in it as per your requirement. Check below example.

http://androidexample.com/Dynamically_Create_View_Elements__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=115&aaid=137